Emacs : Symbol's value as variable is void use-package
After linking to archives, this of how I am currently bootstrapping use-package in .emacs.
It is mostly boiler plate code I found on another post.
I can see use-package as being installed in package.el
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
 (package-refresh-contents)
 (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-and-compile
 (setq use-package-always-ensure t
       use-package-expand-minimally t))

Then I go on to use it to import a bunch of packages
(use-package taureg)
I think package-installed-p is failing and leading to this error void assignment to use-package. This is the debugger output with --debug-init option to emacs.

    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable use-package)
      eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2510
      load-with-code-conversion("/home/.emacs" "/home/.emacs" t t)
      load("~/.emacs" t t)
      #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1e0f4d>)()
      command-line()
      normal-top-level()


Lost on how to resolve it. Any help will be appreciated.

how are you using use-package at "position 2510"?  The void-variable error makes it sound like a syntax issue

Thanks a lot, you solved it. There was missing ( paren somewhere deep buried below. I believe it was treating use-package as a global and trying to get its value.
